# Is it possible to calculate the energy level of a ground state of an electron?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, photons, electrons

All throughout my homework the lowest electron level (ground state)  is never referred to as a number. Is it possible to calculate it numerically?

I have wondered this because a question asked "what will be the energy or energies of the photon emitted? If the atom is bombarded with x energy from an electeon. "

Since the question is asking about photon energy,  I had to figure out the exact numerical energy for level 3,2, and 1(ground state). [was doing a 3 energy level emission ]

Note: the atom being bombarded is unknown (Hence cannot use Rydberg formula)

Comment: see for hydrogen http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html

Comment: If you can choose the energy with which you bombard the unknown atom, you can vary it until you get two types of emitted photon: those corresponding to the 3->2 and and the 3->1 transitions. Assuming you knew the numeric energy of the 2nd or 3rd level you could then use algebra to find the numeric energy of the ground state

Comment: @annav , thanks for the resource, but I can't use the formula as it is optimized for hydrogen ( 1 electron). Although I am interested if there is a formula that works for more than 1 electron

Comment: @BillyKalfus I believe you're actually right. E[3->1] - E[3->2] = E[2->1] which is basically the ground state . Thanks